# getParcelable in kotlin not parsing to model object correctly Android

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

> I use @Parcelize to make data class Parcelable like

```
@Parcelize
data class QuestionBO(val title: String, val options: List<String>, val correctOptionIndex: Int,
                      val dateCreated: Date, val tags: List<String>, val questionType: Int,
                      val userID: String, val userName: String, val totalLikes: Int,
                      val imageUrl: String) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", emptyList(), 1, Date(), emptyList(), 3, ""
            , "", 34, "")
}
```

And calling and passing data to fragment like

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(
                QuestionFragment.newInstance(singleQuestion), "QuestionFragment").commit()
```

**newInstance Method**

```
companion object {
        private const val KEY_QUESTION_BO = "key_question_bo"

        fun newInstance(aQuestion: QuestionBO) = QuestionFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle(2).apply {
                putParcelable(KEY_QUESTION_BO, aQuestion)
            }
        }
    }
```

And in **onViewCreated** I am getting it using arguments like

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if(arguments != null){
            mQuestionBO = arguments!!.getParcelable<QuestionBO>(KEY_QUESTION_BO) as Nothing?

            /*var bundle = arguments!!.getBundle("bundle")
            bundle.getParcelable<QuestionBO>(KEY_QUESTION_BO)*/
        }
    }
```

**Notes**

I debug argument it shows data in onViewCreated but don't convert it to QuestionBO

[image]

What's wrong in the given statement!!!

```
arguments!!.getParcelable<QuestionBO>(KEY_QUESTION_BO) as Nothing?
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm pretty sure you should use `getParcelable<QuestionBO>(KEY_QUESTION_BO) as QuestionBO?`

And then from what I can see from your debugger, `result.mMap.value[0]` is indeed recognized as a `QuestionBO` object.

Looks good to me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `as Nothing?` you're using is the wrong part.
You're saying that the object you retrieve is of type `Nothing?` whereas you're trying to get a `QuestionBO?`.

As @shkschneider said, replace `Nothing?` with `QuestionBP?` and your code will work properly.